# Odoo - hide a website menu base on website fields

Tags: web, view, menu, odoo, hidden

I have a website menu defined by this code:

```
        <record id="website_menu_apps" model="website.menu">
          <field name="name">Apps</field>
          <field name="url">/apps</field>
          <field name="parent_id" ref="website.main_menu" />
          <field name="sequence" type="int">19</field>
        </record>
```

and a field defined by this code:

```
class Website(models.Model):
        _inherit = 'website'
        dedicate_apps_store = fields.Boolean(string='Dedicated Apps Store', default=True)
```

How can I make website menu disappear when user set website.dedicate_apps_store to False?

Comment: You need to Inherit the template that renders these menus to handle the new menu, I think it's called `submenu` I'm not sure in website module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<template id="custom_layout" inherit_id="website.layout" name="custom layout">
  <xpath expr="//ul[@id='top_menu']/t/t" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="t-if">submenu.name != 'Apps' or website.dedicate_apps_store</attribute>
  </xpath>
</template>
```

You inherit `webiste.layout` and set `position="attributes"` then you can write your condition inside the attribute tag.